Is it normal for iabbrev to make vim slower to respond to key presses?
I am using neovim, from inside PowerShell on Windows 10.
I am working my way through "Learn Vimscript the Hard Way", and have set up the following iabbrev commands in my ~.vimrc file:
iabbrev waht what 
iabbrev tehn then

And I've noticed that entering text has become sluggish, i.e. in insert mode, it can take up to a second after pressing a character key, before the character is printed on screen.
I can see how iabbrev would mean checking something on each key press, but I wasn't expecting such a delay. Is that normal?

I don't see this issue in Vim on macOS. Are those abbreviations the only thing your vimrc? What version of Neovim do you have? To answer the titular question, no, it's not normal

I'm using Neovim version 0.10.0. I now see that the problem is intermittent, so most likely not caused specifically by the iabbrev commands. (The vimrc also contains some mappings for putting quotes around currently selected text - these weren't causing a delay).

First confirm (using techniques in How to debug my vimrc) that the abbreviations are the source of the problem. Having other unrelated things interfere makes it harder to pinpoint the issue.
